# Oracle Apex 5.1 - PL/SQL in Dynamic Action Error

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I have a plsql code that when i run from a Dynamic Action on button click, gives me this error "**Ajax call returned server error ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error for Execute PL/SQL Code.**", but that same code if created under Page Process -> Processing, runs without any error. Cant figure out what is causing this error in dynamic action. Here is the code

```
DECLARE
    I_VCNAME VARCHAR2(200);
    I_LPARAMS PK_JRXML2PDF_REPGEN.TPARAMLIST;
    I_VCDIR VARCHAR2(200);
    I_VCFILENAME VARCHAR2(200);
    bl BLOB;
BEGIN
    I_VCNAME:='Fundraiser_Stats';
    I_VCDIR := 'FUNDAMENTAL_FTP';
    I_LPARAMS(1).vcName:='date_from';
    I_LPARAMS(1).vcValue:=:R1_FROM_DATE;
    I_LPARAMS(2).vcName:='date_to';
    I_LPARAMS(2).vcValue:=:R1_TO_DATE;
    I_LPARAMS(3).vcName:='fundraiser';

    FOR fundraiser_name IN (SELECT DISTINCT B.FUNDRAISER fundraiser FROM WAYSACT_SRC_VW A, PLEDGE_EXT B WHERE A.PLEDGE_ID = B.PLEDGE_ID
                       AND (NVL(:R1_FROM_DATE,'0') = '0' OR NVL(:R1_TO_DATE,'0') = '0' OR A.PLEDGE_DATE BETWEEN :R1_FROM_DATE AND :R1_TO_DATE))
        LOOP
            I_LPARAMS(3).vcValue:= fundraiser_name.fundraiser;
            I_VCFILENAME := fundraiser_name.fundraiser||'-'||to_char(sysdate,'dd-Mon-yyyy')||'.pdf';
            PK_JRXML2PDF_REPGEN.PR_RUN_TO_FILE(I_VCNAME => I_VCNAME, I_LPARAMS => I_LPARAMS, I_VCDIR => I_VCDIR,I_VCFILENAME => I_VCFILENAME);
    END LOOP fundraiser_name;
    APEX_APPLICATION.STOP_APEX_ENGINE;
END;
```

Comment: Did you check if you have any NULLS in that select query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for [ORA-06502](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_06502_pl_sql_numeric_value_error.htm): PL/SQL: numeric or value error is :-

1- you passed null value to the back end stored procedure, check in logs whether value is passed or not.

2- when you send invalid data type.